# Ajax, Rest, Flask, SQLAlchemy, JSON : create data

Tags: python, ajax, json, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a problem when I want add new data in file JSON and in SQLAlchemy Database.

**My form for add new data :**

```
<form id="form"  name="formquestions" style="text-align:center;" method="POST">
    <p>
        <h3>Title </h3>
        <input type="text" id="title" required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <h3>Answer 1 </h3>
        <input type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <h3>Answer 2 </h3>
        <input type="text" required>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="buttonquestion" class="btn-success btn" type="submit" value=" Create the question " />
    </p>
</form>
```

**My request Ajax :**

```
$(function() {
$('#form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var answer1=$('#firstAlternative').val();
    var answer2=$('#secondAlternative').val();
    var q= {
        "title": title,
        "firstAlternative":  answer1,
        "secondAlternative": answer2,
    };
    var data=JSON.stringify(q);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/api/questions",
        data:data,
        dataType:"json",
        contentType:"application/json",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            },
        error: function(){console.log('Error');}

        });
        return false;
});
```

});

**My view :**

```
@app.route('/api/questions', methods=['POST'])
def create_question():
    print(request.json)
    if not request.json or not 'title' in request.json:
        abort(400)

    question = {
        'id': quests[-1]['id'] + 1,
        'title': request.json['title'],
        'firstAlternative': request.json.get('firstAlternative', ""),
        'secondAlternative': request.json.get('secondAlternative', ""),
    }
    db.session.add(question)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(question.to_json()), 201, 
    {'Location': url_for('get_post', id=question.id, _external=True)}
```

**Error of server display in terminal :**

```
    127.0.0.1 - - [01/Apr/2015 17:40:08] "POST /api/questions HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/dzde/UNIVERSITE/WEB/ProjetSondage/sondages/views.py", line 53, in create_question
    db.session.add(question)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 150, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1490, in add
    raise exc.UnmappedInstanceError(instance)
UnmappedInstanceError: Class '__builtin__.dict' is not mapped
```

So I have this error 500 in internal servor...
In request Ajax, not success just error...

Thank you

Comment: Your flask server should be showing an error. Please post that as well.

Comment: My post was modified, thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, you're trying to add an arbitrary dict to the database. Since you're using SqlAlchemy, <strike>here's a bit on mapping:</strike>

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_columns.html  This is a better resource for specifying classes explicitly: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#specifying-classes-explcitly

If you don't already, you should have a model class which represents the table in the database; the link above goes into that. You should then create an instance of that class, and pass *that* into the db.session.add() call.

I'm unfamiliar with how SqlAlchemy works, but I'll look a little into it now out of curiosity; if the above advice doesn't help, I'll see if I can find more on the subject in their docs.

Edit:

So I found this: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html

If you follow the steps in "Basic Use" and you have a "question" table existing already, you should then be able to use a "question" class.

Answer (score 0):

I seen your code in jquery seem not correct request in html id :

your html code is should be like this :

```
<p>
    <h3>Title </h3>
    <input type="text" id="title" required>
</p>
<p>
    <h3>Answer 1 </h3>
    <input type="text" id="firstAlternative" required>
</p>
<p>
    <h3>Answer 2 </h3>
    <input type="text" id="secondAlternative" required>
</p>
<p>
```

your jquery request is :

```
var title = $('#title').val();
var answer1=$('#firstAlternative').val();
var answer2=$('#secondAlternative').val();
```

hope it can help :)